# Formal Definition of Algebraic Variety

Tags: polynomials, notation, projective-space, affine-varieties

*On Wikipedia, an [Algebraic Variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety) is defined (I think) as either an [Affine Variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_variety) or a [Projective Variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_variety). From my understanding, an affine variety is the set of common zeroes of a collection of polynomials. And from the wiki, a projective variety is as well, but is also a closed subvariety of a projective space, where closed refers to the Zariski topology. Finally, a [quasi-projective variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-projective_variety) is a locally closed subset of a projective variety. The quasi-* is used to define projective variety, but is defined in terms of it so it's a bit cyclical.*

More specifically (as specific as I could find), given a set $S \subset F[x_1, \dotsc ,x_n]$ of polynomials, the [**affine variety**](http://www.shsu.edu/~ldg005/data/689/L1.pdf) defined by $S$ is the set

$$V(S) := \{a \in A^n \mid f(a) = 0\ \ \ \forall f \in S\}$$

This is an affine subvariety of $A^n$ or simply a *variety*.

That's as specific as I found definitions for affine variety and projective variety.

I am wondering if one could:

1. Provide a formal definition of *algebraic varieties* (independent of sheaves/schemes).
2. And if the definition includes projective/affine varieties, to also define those. Trying to get an intuition of a formal definition of these 3 (affine, projective, and algebraic varieties).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at the book written by Shaferevich "basic algebraic geometry."